# Hamming Distance

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, combinations, cryptography

I have a another question about calculating the size of a subset of codes.
$n := 2^q$ for a natural number $q$

$d_H(v,w) := \left| \{ i \in \{1,\ldots,n\} \; | \; v_i \neq w_i\}\right|$ for 
$v:=(v_1,\ldots,v_n),w:=(w_1,\ldots,w_n) \in \{0,1\}^n$

I have the following sets:

$V_i := \{ v \in \{0,1\}^n \; | \; d_H(v,w_i) = \frac{n}{2}\}$ for $i \in \{0, \ldots, q \}$

where

$w_0 := (0,0,\ldots,0) \in \{0,1\}^n$, 
$w_1 := (0,1,0,1,0,1,\ldots) \in \{0,1\}^n$, 
$w_2 := (0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1\ldots) \in \{0,1\}^n$, 
$w_3 := (0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,\ldots) \in \{0,1\}^n$, 
and so on.. i hope you understand what i mean by $w_i$, they have $2^{i-1}$ zeros, then $2^{i-1}$ ones, then $2^{i-1}$ zeros and so on and 
$i \in \{0, \ldots, q\}$. I could formulate it with a definition, but i think this should be more understandable.

and i want to calculate

$\left| \bigcup_{i = 0}^{k} V_i\right|$, $k \in \{0, \ldots, q\}$

So for instance for $n=8$ we have the following:
$w_0 = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$ 
$w_1 = (0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)$ 
$w_2 = (0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1)$ 
$w_3 = (0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)$ 
and $|V_i| = \binom{8}{4}$ but what is
  $\left| \bigcup_{i = 0}^{k} V_i\right|$, $k \in \{0, \ldots, q\}$? For that i need to know the intersection between the $V_i$'s, but what is it?

EDIT: An analogous problem which is practically the same is to calculate the following:

$\left|\bigcap_{i=0}^{k} \; \{ v \in \{0,1\}^n \; | \; d_H(v,w_i) < \frac{n}{2}\}\right|$

I think this is even much harder to solve, but when i have this solution i can figure out the other.

Any solution with "inaccuracy" $\mathcal{O}(h)$ for a function $h$ is also fine (better than nothing. :D), so for instance

$\left| \bigcup_{i = 0}^{k} V_i\right| = k \cdot \binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}} + \mathcal{O}(h)$, $k \in \{0, \ldots, q\}$

But this $h$ should be smaller than the first function $k \cdot \binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}$.

I would appreciate any help. :)
Thanks,

Comment: Is $n$ a power of 2$ then?

Comment: Yes, $n := 2^i$ for a natural number $i$

Answer (score 1):

I have written only few examples calculated via computer. Maybe they'll help to figure out general formula.

If $n=2^q$, then denote
$$M_n(k) = \left| \bigcup_{i = 0}^{k} V_i\right|, \quad k \in \{0, 1, \ldots, q\}.$$

---

$n=4 \quad (q=2):$

$w_0=0000,$

$w_1=0101,$

$w_2=0011;$

$M_4(0) = 6 = \binom{n}{n/2}$;

$M_4(1) = 8$;

$M_4(2) = 8 \quad(=50 \%)$;

---

$n=8\quad (q=3):$

$w_0=0000\;0000,$

$w_1=0101\;0101,$

$w_2=0011\;0011;$

$w_3=0000\;1111;$

$M_8(0) = 70 = \binom{n}{n/2}$;

$M_8(1) = 104$;

$M_8(2) = 120$;

$M_8(3) = 128 \quad(=50\%)$;

---

$n=16\quad (q=4):$

$w_0=0000\;0000\;0000\;0000,$

$w_1=0101\;0101\;0101\;0101,$

$w_2=0011\;0011\;0011\;0011;$

$w_3=0000\;1111\;0000\;1111;$

$w_4=0000\;0000\;1111\;1111;$

$M_{16}(0) = 12870 = \binom{n}{n/2}$;

$M_{16}(1) = 20840$;

$M_{16}(2) = 25720$;

$M_{16}(3) = 28672$;

$M_{16}(4) = 30432 \quad(\approx 46.4355 \%)$;

---

$n=32\quad (q=5):$

$w_0=0000\;0000\;0000\;0000\;0000\;0000\;0000\;0000,$

$w_1=0101\;0101\;0101\;0101\;0101\;0101\;0101\;0101,$

$w_2=0011\;0011\;0011\;0011\;0011\;0011\;0011\;0011\;$

$w_3=0000\;1111\;0000\;1111\;0000\;1111\;0000\;1111;$

$w_4=0000\;0000\;1111\;1111\;0000\;0000\;1111\;1111;$

$w_5=0000\;0000\;0000\;0000\;1111\;1111\;1111\;1111;$

$M_{32}(0) = 601080390  = \binom{n}{n/2}$;

$M_{32}(1) = 1036523880 $;

$M_{32}(2) = 1351246968$;

$M_{32}(3) = 1578186752$;

$M_{32}(4) = 1741440992$;

$M_{32}(5) = 1858600192 \quad(\approx 43.2739\%)$.

Comment: I have verified these calculations.

Comment: @saulspatz and Oleg567. Could you send me your program perhaps? I have hardcoded it for some fixed dimensions and it looks ugly. I want to use it in my thesis. So maybe i can fix mine then.

Comment: My code is at https://gist.github.com/saulspatz/99443660137356aa29baa5dbe321fa16

Comment: I used arrays, so I mean **saulspatz**'s code is much more elegant than my.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
Computer calculations have shown that my idea was wrong.  I initially deleted the answer, but then I realized that the first part of it was correct, and might be useful, so I'm leaving it.

We know that $V_0$ is just the set of vectors with $4\text{ } 1-$bits.  What about the other $V_i?$  Let $v$ be a vector at Hamming distance $4$ from some $w_i, i >0.$  Say $v$ has $k$ one-bits at the $0$ positions of $w_i.$  Then $v$ must have $4-k$ zero-bits at the $1$ positions of $w_i,$ so $k$ one-bits at those positions, and $2k$ one-bits in all.  That is, every member of the union has an even number of one-bits (and an even number of zero-bits.)

Now, does the reverse inclusion hold? It's easy to see that it does in the example case ($n=8.)$  At this point, I jumped to the conclusion that it would hold in general, but this is **FALSE.**  Still, we know that there are no vectors with an odd number of one-bits in the union.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't understand your third second paragraph.
I mean the paragrah which begins with "Now.." and ends with "You can take it from here".

Comment: I'll try to edit it to make my idea plainer.

Comment: Thanks, i understand it now, it's hard to figure out the general case, but maybe i should think about it for a few hours. I have also updated an analogous problem in my initial question post, maybe that can help.

Comment: If the calculations in the other answer are correct, then my idea won't work in the general case.  I'm going to write a program to verify them.  If they're right, this answer is worthless, and I'll delete it.

Comment: i have verified the case $n=8$ and this is correct.

Comment: @SvEn I checked the calculation for $n=32$ and I also get 1,858,600,192 so my idea is wrong.

Comment: Thanks anyway. :)